# Chrome - Unexpected token Illegal. Firefox und. string literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome

I have following script:

```
    jQuery('#content-page-<?php echo $post->ID ?>')
    .data('content','<div class="page-content"><?php echo $post->post_content; ?>');
```

In

```
    '<div class="page-
```

The

```
'
```

symbol is not understood correctly and I get the

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

AND

```
unterminated string literal
```

error in chrome and firefox.

What is the problem?

### UPDATE 1

The

```
    <?php echo $post->post_content; ?>
```

How to handle multiline text? The problem seems to be in multiline.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is. But it might help to post the rendered HTML rather than the server-side code. You probably need to escape the content from the post.

Comment: Please reformat your code, it is hard to understand.

Comment: @DaveNewton the question is about the ' symbol wrongly understood.

Comment: @Sarfraz, what you don't understand here?

Comment: @JevgeniSmirnov Right, but as posted the code doesn't match up, see? Which is why I think you need to escape the the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any apostrphes in the php output? If so remember it becomes "raw text" so if it echos "I'm bob" it'll render as `'content',';I'm bob'` (notice the middle quote). So you should use something like `addslashes($post->$post_content)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php to escape the output.

Comment: @Raeki, it seems to be a content, because when I remove echo, problem dissapears.

Comment: @Raeki, It is multiline text.

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump($post->$post_content)` just to see if there's anything funky (and preferably post it here). Remember that `\n` will only make a new line in the source code (you want the html `<br>`)